# Sencha Touch: How to get a list item template to be non-scrollable?

Tags: sencha-touch, ext.list

I have a working Ext.List object in my Sencha Touch application.  I'm rendering each item in the list using the List's itemTpl property.  I'm noticing that each individual list item can be scrolled in addition to the whole list which is definitely not what I'm after.

Does anyone have any advice on how to get the individual list items not to scroll?  I've tried setting the outermost div in the itemTpl template to have a specified height and overflow:hidden...but this does not prevent the scrolling behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it the default HTML scrollbar as rendered by the browser, or is it the built-in scroll feature of Sencha Touch (the iScroller which fades in and out)? If it's the latter, try setting the `scroll` attribute of that ListItem object to `false`.

If the former, there's obviously a problem with your CSS selector. Could you share your code if it's this one?

Comment: It turned out being a layout manager issue -- but I did have the scroll attributes set incorrectly as well so accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the height of the list-element, so all the content of a single list-item is visible (so you can't scroll anymore)?